# Determining a scheme $X$ is affine from $Qcoh(X)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

My question is a subquestion of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192826/quasi-coherent-sheaves-schemes-and-the-gabriel-rosenberg-theorem). I do not want to use full reconstruction theorems.

The settings is the following. Let $X$ be a scheme. Assume that the adjunction in [TAG01BH](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01BH) of the stacks project is actually an adjoint equivalence. As is the case for every affine scheme.
Is $X$ affine? Or, which is the same, is the canonical map $X\rightarrow \mbox{Spec } O_X(X)$ an iso?

What I tried thus far is proving all hypothesis of Serre's vanishing theorem and invoking it. The problem: how to prove that there exist 'enough' acyclic resolutions inside $Qcoh(X)$ as is the case for $Qcoh(\mbox{Spec } O_X(X))$ since $\widetilde{I}$ is flasque for injective modules $I$. Any hints?

Any hints in general are also welcome.

Comment: Repost to mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/208422/determining-a-scheme-x-is-affine-from-qcohx